# How to show Database data in google maps on my website?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some dynamic data. I want to call this data dynamically in google maps location positions. When user clicks the location, user should be able to see details and photo of particular location. User should be able to filter the data as per his requirement and view filtered location.

Kindly let me know what type of API i should go for. I have searched alot and i came across Google maps api, google geo, google places api, fusiontables, spreadsheets, xml, kml, javascript, webservice and much more techniques and services.

I am working on asp.net site and sql database, is there any way to work with the same platform. Else please give me proper and easy dynamic way to use the service.

I want the exact maps features used in following site : http://inspire.makemytrip.com/inspire/

Thank You

**P.S. : Whoever doing Downvote for this post should first Note that Google maps API 3 official group has themselves mailed me to add Question here so if you dont wish to answer atleast dont downvote.**

Comment: What have you done so far. If you are new to maps I suggest using Google Maps api V3,PHp & Mysql

Comment: @davidstrachan is it possible working in asp.net and sql database  ?

Comment: Yes but  it is better using php/MySQL as most applications use this. I have tried using ASP & Access database but as there is not much help available it was like reinventing wheel

Comment: @davidstrachan ya exactly.. but i have already built huge website using asp.net n sql server hence it will be difficult to incorporate php n mysql i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Google Maps API V3 with PHP/MySQL as there are numerable tutorials available.

If you insist on using ASP [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET) is a start.

Comment: Thank You very much for the help.

But i am still looking for more dynamic features like http://inspire.makemytrip.com/inspire/

Comment: All the features can be obtained using the API but as the majority of sites do not use ASP.net It is up to you to adapt things to ASP